# Infopath: Validate Status field when there is change in Date

Tags: infopath, validation

I have a non-required field called "EntryDate". But if status changed to "Processing" then end user has to populate the "EntryDate". I can't seem to get this working. Please suggest what are my options or a solution.

Modified: I added validation on the EntryDate. Condition: Status="Processing". This works half way. Now, When I select "Processing", it prompts to enter EntryDate. I enter a date but validation wont quit even if the EntryDate is now populated with Date.

As always, truly appreciated your feedback and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you may be able to do is when the status is changed to processing put an action rule that makes a label visable next to the EntryDate field that indicates to populate.

Then if you have a submit button, add an action rule on this that double checks the fields in question to make sure they are as they should be: If status is Processing EntryDate should have a date.
If this is not the case, have a message (another label) populate that says something to the affect of "Make sure EntryDate is filled out"  Then exit remaining rules.

If everything is how it should be, have another rule on the submit button that submits the data.

So it would be something like:

Status field rule = If processing then set label for Entry Date to Required

Submit Button rule:
Rule 1 check to see if EntryDate is pupulated, if not, message label and exit out of rules.
Rule 2 if EntryDate is populated then submit data.

May be better ways to do this but this is off the top of my head :)

Comment: THANK YOU. THANK YOU. THANK YOU. 3 times because you took time to explain each step and understood the issue. Thanks again. It worked.

Comment: Glad I could help Laura!